# Resizing controls to maintain original proportion size Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, size, controls

I'm trying to resize my control and maintain they're current position. I've tried doing it by keeping the original proportion in list and comparing it and resizing it accordingly whenever the size of the form is changed.

The result http://prntscr.com/bc796l -> http://prntscr.com/bc79a2

Can you guide me where my problem is or suggest a different approach

```
private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control.ControlCollection controls = Controls;
        List<Size> newSizes = new List<Size>();
        for (int j = 0; j < controls.Count; j++)
        {
            int widthProportion = Bounds.Width / controls[j].Width;
            int heightProportion = Bounds.Height/controls[j].Height;
            string controlName = controlProportions[j].Item1;

            int originalWidthProportion = controlProportions[j].Item2;
            int originalHeightProportion = controlProportions[j].Item3;
            if (controls[j].Name == controlName)
            {
                if (widthProportion > originalWidthProportion)
                {
                    while (widthProportion > originalWidthProportion)
                    {
                        originalWidthProportion++;
                    }
                }
                else if (widthProportion < originalWidthProportion)
                {
                    while (widthProportion < originalWidthProportion)
                    {
                        originalWidthProportion--;
                    }
                }
                if (heightProportion > originalHeightProportion)
                {
                    while (heightProportion > originalHeightProportion)
                    {
                        originalHeightProportion++;
                    }
                }
                else if (heightProportion < originalHeightProportion)
                {
                    while (heightProportion < originalHeightProportion)
                    {
                        originalHeightProportion--;
                    }
                }
                newSizes.Add(new Size(Bounds.Width/originalWidthProportion, Bounds.Height/originalHeightProportion));
                controlProportions[j] = new Tuple<string, int, int>(controls[j].Name, originalWidthProportion,
                    originalHeightProportion);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < controls.Count; j++)
        {
            controls[j].Size = newSizes[i];
        }
    }
```

That's how I originally populate the list :

```
private static readonly List<Tuple<string,int, int>> controlProportions = new List<Tuple<string,int, int>>();

    private void SetControlProportions()
    {
        Control.ControlCollection controls = Controls;
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            int heightProportion = Bounds.Height / control.Height;
            int widthProportion = Bounds.Width / control.Width;
            controlProportions.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>(control.Name,widthProportion, heightProportion));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The most obvious error: Integer division. Do not use int but float for your proportions!  `float heightProportion = 1f * Bounds.Height / control.Height;` etc..

Comment: I updated the variables and now they are double's but i get error here http://prntscr.com/bc7htm

Comment: Indeed. 'loss of fraction' is what happens. So change all to float (or double); this includes all declarations where you need to store the proportions.. When setting the integer properties __cast back to int__!  `Size sz = new Size((int)someFloatWidth, (int)someFloatHeight)`..

Comment: No the problem is that unless i cast the result `Bounds.Height / control.Height;` to float or double it will return a `int` i did all your instructions but still the controls are getting really tiny.

Comment: Look again at what I wrote: `1f * ` is not doing nothing..

Comment: I added this but nothing has changed.

Comment: Do use the debugger to check the calculations!

Comment: without *1f http://prntscr.com/bc7l98 with *1f http://prntscr.com/bc7l2v. Nothing is changing I don't even understand how multiplying something by 1 changes anything.

Comment: Well `1f` is not `1` :  it enforces a cast before losing the fraction. But maybe the numbers are right and the error comes from an earlier stage.. You need to debug it as we can't do it for you!